# Date prototype property

Tags: javascript

As I am jumping into Javascript a little deeper, I got this odd result when trying a test.

```
function CustomeObject() {
    this.type = "custom";
};
var node1 = document.createTextNode(Date.prototype);
var node2 = document.createTextNode(CustomeObject.prototype);

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(node1);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(node2);
```

And the result is as follow:

**Invalid Date [object Object]**

As I read from one source on the internet and it says: the **prototype** is a buil-in **property** of any object, and it's actually an object itself. But this test failed with the Date Object. 
Could you tell me what wrong with my code to test Date **prototype property**?
Thank you!

Comment: Guess `document.createTextNode(Date.prototype);` is triggering a call to `Date.prototype.toString` and that is a invalid date, try `document.createTextNode(Object.prototype.toString.call(Date.prototype));` to get what I think is your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `Date.prototype` to `document.createTextNode()` it will implicitly call `toString()` on the passed object.

The default output of `toString()` is `[object Object]`, as seen in your second test.

However `Date.prototype` has its *own* `toString()` function whose purpose is to return the current `Date` object (i.e. `this`) as text.

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.toString()); // outputs current date
console.log(now);            // does the same due to implicit toString() call
```

When you call that function directly its `this` pointer incorrectly contains `Data.prototype` instead of a date object, hence the `"Invalid Date"` output.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Date.prototype` is an object whose `.toString()` returns `Invalid Date`.

```
var d = Date.prototype;
console.log(d); // will output 'Invalid Date', because the object doesn't have any date info.
d.setFullYear(2012);
console.log(d); // will output the date string.
```

Comment: Just that `Date.prototype` is an invalid date.